# trying to generate xls report using dynamic jasper 5.1.2 and struts 2 but have some problem with my action class but can't figure out

Tags: java, struts, dynamic-jasper

This is my desired output.

[this image is of my report output whis is generate by my standalone application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFo8p.png)I am able to generate the DynamicJasper report using my stand alone application but when I am trying to integrate my code in web application I am getting NullPointerException at this line

```
   session=request.getSession(false)

    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Neha/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Neha/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.7/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.itac.action.TripReportAction.getSMSReport(TripReportAction.java:250)
        at TestTripReportAction.toSMS(TestTripReportAction.java:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: Please clarify what is your problem: which error/result do you get, what is the expected result etc.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. "I have a problem" is insufficient: what's happening? What's supposed to happen? Etc. Why do you write the response before doing any work?

Comment: I want to generate report for trips for a school bus in excel format I am using hibernate session with MySQL 5.1.6 DB but not able to fetch data.Getting this exception java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.itac.action.TripReportAction.getSMSReport(TripReportAction.java:250) which is this line  session=request.getSession(false)

Comment: when I am editing my question previous code was deleted